# Typescript: constrain argument of function to be a key of an object associated with a value of a particular type

Tags: typescript, generics, keyof

Is there a way to make the following type check?

```
function getNumberFromObject<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T): number {
  return obj[key] // ERROR: obj[key] might not be a number
}
```

I want to specify that `key` should not only be a key of `T`, but a key with a `number` value.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this so that both the callers and the implementation of `getNumberFromObject<T>` type check correctly is this:

```
function getNumberFromObject<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof any>(
  obj: T, 
  key: K
): number {
  return obj[key] // okay
}
```

And when you call it:

```
getNumberFromObject({dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24}, "dog"); // okay
getNumberFromObject({dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24}, "cat"); // error
getNumberFromObject({dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24}, "moose"); // okay
getNumberFromObject({dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24}, "squirrel"); // error
```

That all works well, except that the errors you get are a little obscure in that it complains that `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dog' does not exist in type 'Record<"somebadkey", number>'`.  This complaint is an [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and isn't really the issue.

If you want to make it so that callers get a better error, you could use a more complicated [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) like this:

```
function getNumberFromObject<T, K extends keyof any & {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never
}[keyof T]>(
  obj: T,
  key: K
): T[K] {
  return obj[key] // okay
}

getNumberFromObject({ dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24 }, "dog"); // okay
getNumberFromObject({ dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24 }, "cat"); // error
getNumberFromObject({ dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24 }, "moose"); // okay
getNumberFromObject({ dog: 2, cat: "hey", moose: 24 }, "squirrel"); // error
```

In this case, `T` is unconstrained, but `K` is forced to be just those keys from `T` where `T[K]` is a `number`.

Now the error says `Argument of type '"somebadkey"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"dog" | "moose"'.`, which is more developer-friendly.  Not sure if the extra complexity of signature is worth it to you, though.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

Update: The latter function returns `T[K]`, not `number`.  That could be a good thing, since `T[K]` is possibly more specific than `number`.  For example:

```
interface Car {
  make: string,
  model: string,
  horsepower: number,
  wheels: 4
}
declare const car: Car;
const four = getNumberFromObject(car, 'wheels'); // 4, not number
```

The value `four` is of type `4`, which is more specific than `number`.  If you really want to widen the return type of the function to `number`, you can... although the implementation will balk at that since the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that `T[K]` is assignable to `number` in the generic case.  There are ways to deal with that, but the easiest is to use a type assertion in the implementation (`return obj[key] as any as number`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoIpJAMwFdh4AXDAe2CSwhoDkKwAjCNAMTT0wKLgCsItADwAVJBAAeNCMAAmUJACUJ9NCskBpADRJgnHmgB8x-XMXK1SANYQAnvTJIQwFxYAUJUiR6MQAuJGlDANJnFzD9AIBKMNNuXjwopDRWCjQmYNEAbRiAXSQAejKgxxAXAIBfIgCWdjNeASERcVpfXCQVeiwwgCZjeBAaMIAiAAtXSeMwenooCGGAFiQ640n+rEmEgG5yyvpq2sJSZo5U-kFhMQkaHr6B4dHxqdmXeaRF5dWkEMNlskJMxjR9kcKnI0II0E1WNdzO17l0nr1dm8kODPnMFksVutNts-itIccqjUES0bijOo9npjAe8JqCvj9SQCgcTQVAAI4UDCwiAAG3J0N4cMaFyQGGASjQZAQyAAwiA0OkZaQwCBnGEoDRMMAsJEtb96CpRfrDXKTRlpjoVjB6AB3XjJVpoU2BJAu2aiqBhNb1AKW+Ai9XIeCMA3Y9VhNVoA4BaPAWNkeg5JAAXmYiM9dIe3TGXqQAHI-RAA2XDhSUuYiA1iIRQJBYMqkABZegANwgGjhGoIMso1DojDzNORd3pUgiSBsCiUqnUMXc4SQADJNT6CjY5U5XOvpMUwtI96Ul-Z1PW0gB+BdIZIQPvwmV1IpHjwnvwZfJn71AhiOJEjPC8d0CLIaByPIxE-FxSmhU4qXfaVLnzWkZyLdEXkGZk41ZGY8XNf4iRBHYBnFE4zmpJE2iwtFGVefCcTZYjOTI7ZwSomEpRlK4CwYhkMWYkYCNxb58VIwFgRJAkIB45DznQqd6I6bCmLwsTWKIySSMJGSeUmflBWFMVawlWEdDQ2V5V4JVECQRMIO1XUAQNI07TNRZLRFa1PMA0gHTQJ1XXdExPUC31-RFQMkGDVCZTDCMsmxGMaDjNAE3VZMZVTdNMw1XMBMw9TGJLYwKxiqAayhSo1mMYB6Ay2830bIA)

Comment: Great answer, interesting use of conditional types. I was just wondering in the second version with the more complex signature, although `key` is restricted to a key of `obj` that has a number value, when you do something like `const x = obj[key]` `x` will be of type `T[K]` not number. Is there anything that can be done there?

Comment: `T[K]` is possibly more specific than `number`. I added an update.

Comment: This answer is impressive but could you detail what the complicated part does in the conditional type part, please? It works but I'd like to understand why it works.

Comment: The type `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never}[keyof T]` is usually what I'd call `KeysMatching<T, number>`.  The type `T[K] extends number ? K : never` will be equal to the key if its property is of type `number`; otherwise it will be `never`.  So if `T` is `{a: string, b: number}` and `K` is `"a"` then it becomes `never`, and if `K` is `"b"` then it becomes `"b"`. The mapped type `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never}` makes that the new property values: `{a: never, b: "b"}`. And the `[keyof T]` just gets the union of property type: `never | "b"` which equals `"b"`.

Comment: Read about [keyof/lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types), [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types).  @Telokis

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, it's much clearer now! Is the `keyof any & {...}` a trick or something? I never saw it before

Comment: Wouldn't `<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>` work best?

Comment: @ruohola Does it?   If you do that sometimes the error message is [a little weirder](https://tsplay.dev/m3zgLN).  I suppose whether it's better or worse depends on the use case.

Comment: @jcalz Ahh, that is a bit weird, but it works perfectly for my use case where I use `unknown` instead of `number`. This is anyways the more general solution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQHIgLYCNUBOAYgXNgPK4BWq0APACqKoAeUqYAJgM6IBKtOAU50A0gBpE4ANZg4AdzAA+SaOZsOPRNNQBPOMEQMlACgCwAKESI41AFxHxl6zt0PRlgJQOGAbVEAuogA3s6IBOggBEi2VL6uAZYAvpaWaJg4+MSkFNS0UCbBiJxwyA4ATJIQAIZQDgBEABZ69ZLYcHDcqBUALIhJkvU1UPWeANzWAPSTNtJp6Fh4hCRklDTQhcWlFVW1Dc26rYjtnd2I5X0DiPXAHaMTiNMoHZzMBKQEx6jc3NVoQA

Answer (score 4):

Best solution:

```
const getNumberFromObject = <T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
) => {
  return obj[key];
};
```